# What is the best play strategy for a game called "21"?

Tags: probability, algorithms, problem-solving

There is a game called 21, played orally by ***n*** players and the rules are following:

First player starts by **randomly** saying an integer form [1,3] for his turn, then the next player **randomly** adds to the previous number an integer also from [1,3] an so on by circle, until someone will be forced to say 21 and lose *(the sum can't exceed 21, so if the previous number was 20, player is forced to say 21(his range is{1})*. Likewise, if the previous number was 19, the his range is [1,2]). Then the next player starts a new round. The game continues until there is only 1 player left.

The question is somehow similar to the Josephus problem, but the "random" part is where I got lost. I found that if a player says "$X$", where ***X = 21-(n-1)*** then he definitely won't lose, so I was trying to think of an algorithm that leads players to "$X$", but I am stuck.

My question is: Let one player to be "strategic" and use a certain algorithm in order to win, and the other players will choose entirely randomly, can it be such an algorithm for **n** players?

Comment: What kind of algorithm are you looking for? If the integer used by each player is random, then there's no algorithm to solve it, since the game becomes a game of pure chance like rock-paper-scissors.

Comment: This is not clear at all.  Are you somehow giving one player the ability to override the "random" selections?  And how does the game end if the players skip over $21$ without hitting it exactly?

Comment: Sounds like this may be related to a game called Nim: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nim

Comment: @lulu Sorry, edited. And the "cheating" player will not override random selections, he'll just say an integer based on previous num using the "unexisting algorithm" and win anyway, but as VTand says above I think there is no way for it

Comment: This could be a clear enough question if we say one player is being strategic, and knows all the other players are selecting entirely at random.

Answer (score 1):

I recommend looking at the game "Nim" like Sean Xie suggested. https://www.archimedes-lab.org/How_to_Solve/Win_at_Nim.html
or https://boardgamestrategy.blog/2017/02/13/counting-to-21-strategy/

As the number of players increase, however, there less of a strategy (except in extreme cases) because the other players can cooperate against you; they have a wider range of options, collectively, than you do, so you can't use the sort of strategy that you can use in the two-player version.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).